# How to extract email from Linkedin BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract email from Linkendin and tried all the methods I found on internet.
Even When I try to print all the anchor tags it pulls only last email.

Here is the linkendin code.
[image: Linkendin source snippet from which I want to extract emails]

```
Here is my code:
dim = BeautifulSoup(pg.content)
name =  dim.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'full-name'})
  print name[0].text

for t in dim.find_all('li',attrs={'class':'contact-field'}):
      print t.findChildren()
```

Comment: What linkedin page is that exactly and why don't you use LinkedIn API?

Comment: Could you please link us the page you're trying to scrape. It could be that the other emailaddresses aren't in the DOM yet when you're parsing the html. (e.a. the emailadresses are placed with javascript after the page is loaded)

Comment: Yes! You are right. email adderesss are placed with javascript with a click event on button. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I got it. A javascript is executed to show up the other email ID's .BeautifulSoup can not execute javascript, I will have to use seleniun or something to first execute javascript and extract.

Comment: Could you share the way you did it?

Comment: I dropped this project but you can find how javascript can executed here : https://github.com/pankajthekush/scraping. In this project I extracted email address of top reviewers which were only visible by executing a javascript.